# Vue 3 reactive values returned from a functionf

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a function that produces variables. I need them to be reactive - it might change in time, however Vue does not track these changes

```
    <template>
      {{ parse('foo') }}
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    export default {
      setup() {
        function parse(param) {
          const target = ref('initial value')
    
          setTimeout(() => {
            target.value = 'changed value'
          }, 3000)
    
          return target
        }
    
        return { parse }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Seems you need **reactive** and not **ref** for that. But could you explain what you are trying to display in the template?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to call a method inside template in order to render something, you could define the reactive data outside the function and run the function in the setup or the `onMounted` hook to modify the target property :

```
   <template>
      {{ target }}
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    export default {
      setup() {
        const target = ref('initial value')
  
      function parse(param) {
            setTimeout(() => {
            target.value = 'changed value'
          }, 3000)        
        }
   //call the function 
   parse('foo')

    
        return { target }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: the problem is that I do not know all the "targets" in advance... That's why I use function.. In my example "parse" might be called many times in the template, and with different params it would return different initial values and changed values..

Comment: You could use a button to run the method again

Answer (score 1):

I think you are expecting **initial value** to be displayed and after 3 seconds it being changed to **changed value** however, in your code you are defining target inside the function so **initial value** is never being returned but instead only **changed value** is.

instead `const target = ref('initial value')` should be defined outside of your function and then the function should be called accordingly

```
  <template>
      {{ target }}
    </template>
    
    <script>
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    export default {
      setup() {
        const target = ref('initial value')
        function parse(param) {
          setTimeout(() => {
            target.value = 'changed value'
          }, 3000)
        }
        parse('foo')

        return { target } 
      },
    }
    </script>
```